# Fixed sized multidimensional array arguments

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, constructor, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a generic matrix class in c++. I want to be able to initialize a matrix from a two dimensional double array. Because I'm using templates and therefor matrix sizes need to be known at compile time, I want to make sure that just arrays of a given size can be passed to the constructor. Expressed in code this is:

```
template<unsigned int M, unsigned int N>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(double (&values)[M][N]);
}
```

Now, here comes the odd part: Like expected the following code works like a charm:

```
    double arr [3][3] = { {1,2,3},
                          {1,2,3},
                          {1,2,3} };
    Matrix<3,3>* mat3x3p = new Matrix<3,3>(arr);
```

But when passing the array anonymously the code is broken:

```
Matrix<3,3>* mat3x3p = new Matrix<3,3>({ {1,2,3},
                                         {1,2,3},
                                         {1,2,3} });
```

The same applies also to construction through assignment.
The exact error message is:

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘double (&)[3][3]’
```

Comment: try with `Matrix(double (&values)[][N]);`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. `Matrix(const double (&values)[M][N]);` should, however, work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be binding a temporary to an (lvalue) reference to non-`const`, and that's not allowed. If you change to a reference to `const` then that would work -- although in the case of an array it's a bit weird as *cv*-qualifiers apply to the element type, not the array itself. Nonetheless, if you have

```
Matrix(const double (&values)[M][N]);
```

then

```
Matrix<3, 3>({{ 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 }})
```

is valid in C++11, thanks to list initialization. I don't know of a way to make it work for C++03.

Comment: Interesting, while adding a const qualifier fixes the constructor problem, assignment is still not possible

Comment: @Paranaix When this happens to you, always try adding a level of braces. I.e. `m = {{{ 1, 2, 3 }}, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 }}}`. The new level of braces is for the `Matrix<3, 3>`, so that's equivalent to `m = Matrix<3, 3> {{ 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 }}`.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I think i should declare the constructor "explicit" so that its clear that a conversion constructor is not possible.

Comment: Casting the brace enclosed list to an array solved the problem:  Matrix<3,3> mat3x3 = (double[3][3]) {{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3}};

Comment: @Paranaix This may mean you have reached the limits of your compiler then. Have you tried explicitly writing an `operator=` taking `const int (&)[M][N]`?

Comment: This worked when one created the object first using the default constructor and then assigned the array to it but not when constructing it.

Comment: @Paranaix Oh! That additional level of braces is needed for assignment (maybe) but not for initialization, even when using copy-init syntax (i.e. `T t = expr;`). Although I may be wrong, I too have been bitten by compiler quirks before. You may want to refrain from using those features if you feel your compiler isn't really up to it.

Answer (score 1):

Per the C++ standard initializer lists can only exist at variable declaration.  While a few more lines of code, once compiled your first example should have no more of a foot print than the second.